# How to implement a Java abstract interface in Scala

Tags: scala, oop, scala-java-interop

How do you implement a Java abstract interface in scala?

Abstract interface :

```
public abstract interface KeyIndex<K>
  extends Serializable
{
  public abstract long toIndex(K paramK);

  public abstract Seq<Tuple2<Object, Object>> indexRanges(Tuple2<K, K> paramTuple2);
}
```

Comment: It seems you are attempting to convert Java to Scala? The closest equivalent to an interface is a [trait](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/traits.html) - give that a try.

Comment: You can leave out the `abstract` keyword from your interface and method declarations, an interface and its methods are always abstract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that your `KeyIndex` class is written in Java. In Scala every field not labeled `private` or `protected` is public. There is no `public` keyword in Scala.
But implementing a Java class in Scala is possible:

```
class KeyIndexImpl extends KeyIndex[geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey]{
  override def toIndex(paramK: geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey): Long = 
    1l

  override def indexRanges(paramTuple2: (geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey, geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey)): Seq[(AnyRef, AnyRef)] = 
    Seq((paramTuple2, paramTuple2))
}
```

Comment: thank you. When i implement toIndex , i get the output of type "long" . from the error, type mismatch; found : Long required: geotrellis.spark.io.index.KeyIndex[geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey] , i should get an output of type geotrellis.spark.io.index.KeyIndex

Comment: yes in my example i used Int as the Type Parameter, you have to use geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey. i edited my answer for you

Comment: i get compilation errors by doing the above way.
[ERROR] C:\Users\prasanna.s\workspace\RasterDataAnalysis\src\main\scala\RasterDataPOC\RasterDataAnalysis\ReadTiff.scala:24: error: overriding method toIndex in trait KeyIndex of type (key: geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey)Long;
method toIndex has incompatible type
[ERROR] override def toIndex(paramK: SpatialKey) : KeyIndex[SpatialKey]             ^
[ERROR] C:\Users\prasanna.s\workspace\RasterDataAnalysis\src\main\scala\RasterDataPOC\RasterDataAnalysis\ReadTiff.scala:23: error: class KeyIndexImpl needs to be abstract, since:

Comment: override def toIndex(paramK: SpatialKey) : KeyIndex[SpatialKey]   should be override def toIndex(paramK: SpatialKey): Long, the error is saying, that the return type of the implementation of  toIndex not matches the definition in the base class (java)

Comment: I tried that , but the return type becomes long instead of SpatialKey
--
type mismatch; found : Long required: geotrellis.spark.io.index.KeyIndex[geotrellis.spark.SpatialKey]

Comment: the return type has to be Long, like in the java interface KeyIndex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105806/discussion-between-vds-and-meiko).